# How to add menuentry for CentOS on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: grub2

I have installed Windows 10, CentOS 7 X8 and Ubuntu 16.04 in the same order on a laptop.

Now on the Grub menu does not recognize my CentOS. I can only boot to Ubuntu and Windows.

I would appreciate if someone could help me to edit my grub2 in Ubuntu 16.04

Here are my partitions:

```
jeff@PC2U:~$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME   FSTYPE        SIZE MOUNTPOINT         LABEL
loop1  squashfs    135,5M /snap/gimp/30      
sr0                 1024M                    
loop2  squashfs     81,6M /snap/core/4110    
loop0  squashfs     86,8M /snap/keepassxc/30 
sda                111,8G                    
├─sda4                 1K                    
├─sda2 ntfs         50,3G                    (Windows)
├─sda7 ext4         32,6G /                  (Ubuntu 16.04)
├─sda5 crypto_LUKS  18,6G                    (CentOS 7 - / (root))
├─sda3 ext4          476M                    (CentOS 7 - /boot)
├─sda1 ntfs          549M                    System Reserved (Win7 recovery part.)
└─sda6 crypto_LUKS   9,3G                    (CentOS 7 - /home)
loop3  squashfs     80,8M /snap/keepassxc/33 
jeff@PC2U:~$
```